# INNER JOIN + LEFT JOIN (Double filtering)

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm trying to filter my table where a user has a row in one table, and does not have a row in another. Here's my table structure:

**Here's an SQL Fiddle instead:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e27ed/2

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   user_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(25),
   PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE photos (
   photo_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
   user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(photo_id)
);

CREATE TABLE blocked (
   user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
   blocked_id INT(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users (name) 
VALUES ('returned'), ('not returned'), ('not returned'), ('not returned');

INSERT INTO photos (user_id) 
VALUES (1), (2);

INSERT INTO blocked (user_id, blocked_id) 
VALUES (4, 2);
```

Here's the query that I'm trying:

```
SELECT u.*, min(p.photo_id)
FROM users u
INNER JOIN photos p using(user_id)
LEFT JOIN blocked b ON b.user_id = 4 AND b.blocked_id = u.user_id 
WHERE u.user_id != 4
GROUP BY u.user_id
LIMIT 9;
```

The example data makes it very obvious what the results should be, as the "name" field is filled with `"returned", "not returned"` in this example, user-id 2 is still returned, but he should be removed by the LEFT JOIN, as user-id 4 has user-id 2 in the blocked-id field of the blocked table.

**Expected** results from table:

```
+---------+----------+-----------------+
| user_id |   name   | min(p.photo_id) |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
|       1 | returned |               1 |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
```

**Received** results from query:

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
| user_id |     name     | min(p.photo_id) |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
|       1 | returned     |               1 |
|       2 | not returned |               2 |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to answer this as I see you are comparing blocked_id=user_id, though in blocked table you also have a user_id column. Only you will know that.

But consider the following

```
SELECT u.*, min(p.photo_id),b.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN photos p using(user_id)
LEFT JOIN blocked b ON b.user_id = 4 AND b.blocked_id = u.user_id 
WHERE u.user_id != 4 and b.user_id is null
GROUP BY u.user_id
LIMIT 9;

+---------+----------+-----------------+---------+------------+
| user_id | name     | min(p.photo_id) | user_id | blocked_id |
+---------+----------+-----------------+---------+------------+
|       1 | returned |               1 |    NULL |       NULL |
+---------+----------+-----------------+---------+------------+
```

It turns on the sonar by revealing the b.* columns added as columns 4 and 5. And messes with the `where` clause a bit.

**Edit**:

Cleaned up for production

```
SELECT u.*, min(p.photo_id)
FROM users u
INNER JOIN photos p using(user_id)
LEFT JOIN blocked b ON b.user_id = 4 AND b.blocked_id = u.user_id 
WHERE u.user_id != 4 and b.user_id is null
GROUP BY u.user_id
LIMIT 9;
```

Comment: `blocked_id = u.user_id` is meant to check to see if the current user being checked is blocked by the selected user (in this event `4`). Is there no way to do this without revealing the `b.*` columns? It isn't a HUGE issue, but it's kinda nasty.

Comment: I put them there to show it. They don't belong in the result set when you go to production with it ! So use em in the `where`, don't show em on line 1 of command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `WHERE b.blocked_id IS NULL` to return users that have NOT been blocked by user 4

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one..

```
SELECT u.*, min(p.photo_id)
FROM users u
INNER JOIN photos p using(user_id)
LEFT JOIN blocked b ON b.blocked_id = u.user_id 
GROUP BY u.user_id having min(p.photo_id)<=all(select min(p.photo_id) FROM users u
INNER JOIN photos p using(user_id)
LEFT JOIN blocked b ON b.blocked_id = u.user_id 
GROUP BY u.user_id)
;
```